# If $(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4)$ is jointly normal, is $(X_1 - X_4, X_2-X_3, X_4-X_3)$ (for example) also jointly normal?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

I know that if, for example, $(X, Y)$ is jointly normal, then any linear combination of them is normal.

Now my question is, is a collection of distinct pairwise sums jointly normal? If not, what kind of conditions are required for them to be jointly normal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Affine transformations of multivariate normals are again multivariate normal.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation) In your case,

$$\begin{pmatrix}X_1-X_4 \\ X_2-X_3 \\X_4-X_3 \end{pmatrix} 
=
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\0 & 1& -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}}_{=:M}
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}X_1 \\ X_2 \\ X_3 \\X_4 \end{pmatrix}}_{=:X}
$$
is normal with mean $M\vec{\mu}$ and variance $M\Sigma M^t$, where $\vec\mu$ denotes the mean and $\Sigma$ the covariance matrix of $X$.